# Cassandra RandomPartitioner and "full table scans"

Tags: cassandra

I can't seem to find information on how one would traverse all the rows in a column family using a `RandomPartitioner` to split up keys. The usual approaches to full scans I see listed are "use MapReduce" (which will be an option but isn't for now) and to create a range slices query to retrieve rows in batches, updating the lower bound of the range with the last key seen after every batch. This seems like an odd approach when you can't guarantee an ordering on keys, so I was wondering what the accepted practice is in this situation.

To be clear, this whole column family traversal thing is not a regular occurrence, and is not part of our standard access patterns to the database. It doesn't need to be particularly fast (although it'd be nice, of course!) We just need to do it occasionally to check for garbage and such. We don't expect the rows returned to be a consistent snapshot or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Hadoop MapReduce would be the *right* way to do this, but I understand this is not a viable option for you at the moment.  So you have a couple of possibilities:

1. If your keys have some logical order and can be calculated or otherwise known in advance, you can do a multi-get of a bunch of keys in a batch.
2. You can create a range client similar to the way Cassandra's [ColumnFamilyInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/hadoop/ColumnFamilyInputFormat.java) works.
3. You can do a range slice [using Hector like this](https://github.com/zznate/hector-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/riptano/cassandra/hector/example/PaginateGetRangeSlices.java) or some similar construct in another library.